# How to delete all items from a dynamo db table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new in Dynamo db and my requirement is "I have a big data which i want to store in multiple tables. Before the insertion, the data which is already in tables should be deleted.I have read many answers for this solution and most of them telling that delete table is most efficient way than deleting all items. But my problem is when I delete and re-create all the tables, it took some time to create tables, then how can I insert data in the same functionality? If I set some timeout to insert data but it doesn't work properly all the time."
Anyone here to give the best solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can call dynamo.describeTable() and check the table TableStatus is "DELETING","CREATING" or "ACTIVE" 
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#describeTable-property

Comment: good approach, but I need to perform operation on 3 tables simultaneously. First delete all 3 tables, second create tables, third check for activation of tables which having some timeout or recursion to check active for all 3 tables. and then insert data in batch. Don't you think its a very time taking process and slow down the api.

Comment: Can you have three more tables to store the data when you are deleting and recreating table. Then switch to new tables and migrates data.